# ParseError at [row,col]:[66,34] Message: -xml-names-19990114#AttributeNSNotUnique?Button&layout_column

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an error with my app the error says

```
    ParseError at [row,col]:[66,34] Message:         http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributeNSNotUnique?        Button&layout_column
```

I can't find where the error is.. I don't know which are the row and col... maybe in the xml files?

This is the AndroidManifest file

```
    AndroidManifest.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.***">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="App Name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.appname.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"    />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="appname"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-2703074771097768~4557375307"/>. 
    </application>
```

Answer (score 22):

I had similar issue:

```
ParseError at [row,col]:[8,279]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributeNSNotUnique?androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout&layout_width&http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

What you need to do:

First read the error message carefully, in my case it's mentioned in error message that there is something wrong with:
`ConstraintLayout&layout_width` attribute in my latest layout xml file.

In my case I had mistakenly added `layout_height` and `layout_width` attributes to `<layout>` tag, which is actually meant only for data binding. So just by removing those lines I was able to fix this issue.

The `layout` that I initially had:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

To fix this issue I did:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

Comment: You are a hero (y) Exactly same mistake I did. I don't know what I was thinking lol.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib <3 JazakAllah bro, helping each other makes me happy :)

Comment: Thanks so much man that solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

As the answer [here explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68216526), the error you're getting is getting obscured by an updated version of Gradle. In my case, I also had the [row][col] message, and when I downgraded my Gradle version from 4.2.2 to 4.1.3 and compiled again, it now showed me the real error (I had a duplicated attribute in one of my XMLs) and I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you had trouble like me finding which (xml) layout file has the fault causing this ParseError, try to click Build at the bottom of your screen and click on the `mergeDebugResources` build task. It will give more information than this stupid error :-)

Answer (score 0):

I get the seam problem in my case it's like that

`ParseError at [row,col]:[40,33] Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?TextView&tools:text&tools`

it's very hard to find where is the problem it is.

like this answer
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780877/parseerror-at-row-col66-34-message-xml-names-19990114attributensnotuniqu?answertab=votes#tab-top)

my problem is in some xml file `TextView&tools:text&tools` so i search all my project `Ctrl + Shift + F` then i find my broblem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I forgot to add tools namespace declaration on top of the xml file

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and coincidentally I also just found the solution.
You only need to **check all the xml files on the line(row)** that says error in your build view tool, like this screenshot [Error XML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPrXP.png)
And then, you only need to press alt + enter to fix the error in that line. Or you can delete the code in that line