# string does not contain a valid string resource. Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, string, kotlin

I get this error message:

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Kotlin Projects\Projects\10000Months\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:51:4: Failed to flatten XML for resource 'Turn_Your_Ideas_into_Product' with error: Attempting to flatten xml with unfinished spans.
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Kotlin Projects\Projects\10000Months\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:51:4: string/Turn_Your_Ideas_into_Product does not contain a valid string resource.
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Kotlin Projects\Projects\10000Months\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:65:4: Failed to flatten XML for resource 'Write_a_Short_Book' with error: Attempting to flatten xml with unfinished spans.
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Kotlin Projects\Projects\10000Months\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:65:4: string/Write_a_Short_Book does not contain a valid string resource.
```

whenever I use these strings (below) in values->strings in Android Studio.
Please take a look at them what should I add or remove;

```
<!--Record Your Conversations-->
    <string name="Record_Your_Conversations">
        <font size="17">Record Your Conversations</font>\n
        <font size="13">Is there a subject that you\'re exceptional knowledgeable about? Or even a subject that you\'re really interested in diving into a little deeper? Are you a good listener?…</font>
    </string>


<!--Write a Short Book-->
    <string name="Write_a_Short_Book">
        <font size="17">Write a Short Book</font>\n
        <font size="13">Writing a book is not easy, but we\'ll assist you, and this is especially good avenue to take if you're not interested in audio, video, or physical products…</font>
    </string>
```

**Edit:**

I have other similar strings, like this one:

```
<!--Teach People What You Know-->
    <string name="Teach_People_What_You_Know">
        <font size="17">Teach People What You Know</font>\n
        <font size="13">I bet you know things. Things that other people don\'t know. Music, sales, yoga etc. These are things people are constantly learning…</font>
    </string>
```

It works for them, I don't know what is wrong with the other 2 strings..

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Just putting this here since there have been a few answers already: yes you can use (some) HTML in string resources: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's your problem, you've got an unescaped quote in `Write_a_Short_Book`:

*take if **you're** not interested*

You didn't post `Turn_Your_Ideas_into_Product` (the other one in your error log) but it's probably the same issue

Comment: Thanks a lot for your observation, I actually saw it and ignore it, since it didn't warn me, beacuse it usually warns, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use html like that in the strings.xml. You should either use CDATA[] like below:

```
<string name="string_html"><![CDATA[<b>Html text</b>]]></string>
```

or otherwise like below example:

```
<string name="string_html">&lt;b&gt;Html text&lt;br&gt;&lt;font color=\"#fe2e68\"&gt;text example&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;</string>
```

Comment: I 've added a string similar to the other it works fine.. I thought maybe something is with the syntax of the other two strings, like maybe I used " instead of ', or something..

Comment: I don't think it is possible to include html code in the strings.xml without any of the above ways. Can you share the strings that worked?

Comment: You can: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML